# How to ensure that there is at least one instance of a class?

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I need to ensure that there is at all times during programm execution at least one instance of a certain class. A Singleton won't do because (among other reasons) I might in the future *need* more instances. A static class might as well do but that feels like going global... Also I would like some private members, both functions and variables.

I thought about keeping a shared_ptr somewhere safe, but that seems to be a rough hack.

Is there a standard way to do this?

**edit**

To clarify: it is not a matter of being able to check whether an instance still exists. An instance *must* exist at all times. The reason is that there are static member variables in the class, which should maintain their state.

Comment: Why exactly do you need at least one instance of a certain class?

Comment: How will you access this instance? Can it be constructed lazily?

Comment: @DanF: In order not to loose the state of some static member variables.

Comment: @Luc: yes. That would even be desirable.

Comment: @steffen Now you're asking about something completely different from original question. Please explain.

Comment: a new "manyton" pattern  ;-)

Comment: @steffen - Static members live independently of the class. You can use them without an instance of the class, like `class_name::member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to ensure that there is at all times during programm execution at least one instance of a certain class.

So I guess the solution begins with deciding who is responsible for storing it.

You could: store it internally within the class (static) or return it to the caller/client context (and rely on the client context to keep it). Since you say "A Singleton won't do" the solution should look like this:

```
class TheClass
{
public:
    // this doesn't have to be a std::shared_ptr<WithContext>
    // and probably shouldn't be (see below)
    typedef <implementation-defined> GlobalContext;

    GlobalContext InitContext(); // return instance
};

void main( /* ... */ )
{
    // do this before any code that uses TheClass instances
    auto global_execution_context = TheClass::InitContext();

    // rest of your application code goes here
}
```

> I thought about keeping a shared_ptr somewhere safe, but that seems to be a rough hack.

What do you see as it's drawbacks? If it's because it's an obscure dependency, you can add a test for it, or throw an exception when the context is deleted/affected/not there. You could also ask for a reference to your context in TheClass' constructor.

The reason you shouldn't have GlobalContext be a std::shared_ptr but it's own type, is that this is what your requirements actually amount to:

you need a (new) type of object that keeps common state of TheClass between instances.

Answer (score 1):

I always implement this using internal static counter which was incremented in constructor and decremented in destructor.

And yes, definitely you method to check 'at least one instance' should be static.

UPDATE: OK, I see errors in answers here so I post my answer:

```
class Test
{
private:
  static int m_count;
public:
  Test() { ++m_count; }
  Test(const Test&) { ++m_count; }

  ~Test()
  {
    --m_count;
  }

  static bool hasInstance()
  {
    return (m_count > 0);
  }
};

int Test::m_count = 0;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a static member and set it in constructor/destructor:

```
class Test
{
  static int i;
public:
  Test()
  {
    i++;
  }

  Test(const Test &t) // It's suspicious 
  {
    i++;
  }

  ~Test()
  {
      i--;
  }

  static bool hasInstance()
  {
    return i>0;
  }
};

static int Test::i = 0;
```

Then, you know if `Test` has any instance or not.

Comment: Please add 'static' modifier to hasInstance(). This way your answer is 100% illustration to my approach.

Comment: BTW error: m_hasInstance should not be reset in destructor!!! Probably solution with counter is better.

Comment: You'd need to increment in the copy constructor too (or prevent copying).

Comment: @Bleep Bloop in general you're right, +1. But copy could be blocked, yeh? ;-)

Comment: M.M. +1, now could you add copy constructor? ))

Answer (score 1):

How about a kind of factory class, that contains a collection of all the instances?

Something like:

```
template<typename T>
class least_one_factory
{
    static std::vector<T> instances_;

public:
    least_one_factory()
    {
        // Make sure there is an instance of `T` in our collection
        instance_.push_back(T());
    }

    T& get()
    {
        return instances_.front();
    }

    T& get(int n)
    {
        return instances_.at(n);
    }

    T& create()
    {
        instances_.push_back(T());
        return instances_.back();
    }

    int count() const
    {
        return instances_.size();
    }

    operator T&()
    {
        return get();
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> least_one_factory<T>::instances_;
```

Now you can do:

```
struct some_class {};

least_one_factory<some_class> some_class_factory;
```

The variable `some_class_factory` will contain *at least* one instance of `some_class`. You can get it with `some_class_factory.get()`. If `some_class_factory` is a global variable, then the instance of `some_class` will be created when your program is loaded before `main` is called.

Comment: That is more (but not exactly) what I want ;) If possible, I would like to make this transparent to the rest of the code and not having to write `.get()`

Comment: @steffen Added conversion operator, now it can be used as `some_class var = some_class_factory;` The conversion operator returns only the first instance though. It's hard to make it more "transparent" for the following instances though, especially the creation of them.